# What is this question asking? Geometry

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Rhombus $ABCD$, with side length 6, is rolled to form a cylinder of volume 6 by taping $\overline{AB}$ to $\overline{DC}$. What is $\sin\left(\angle ABC\right)$?

Is it asking for the sin of the angle while it's a cylinder or as a rhombus?
I used the formula for the volume of a cylinder ($6=\pi r^2 H$) to find the height of the rhombus. So is it asking for the sin of the angle while it's a rhombus (Which I can figure out since I know the height) or in cylinder form?

Comment: It asks for the sine of the angle in rhombus form. i.e the one in Pragnya Jha's answer. (Actually, if you measure the angle between the curve $AB$ and the base $BC$ (which is now a circle ) on the final cylinder. You will get same sine of the angle).

Answer (score 1):

It is asking for the sin of the angle in the rhombus form. In the cylindrical form, B and C are essentially the same points so such an angle will have no meaning. The answer comes out to be height/side = $ \pi /9$

Answer (score 0):

Probably in cylinder form, because last given information was about cylinder and its volume,i think so.

Answer (score 0):

Points A,B,C ARE vertices of the rhombus so it might be asking for anangle ABC IN RHOMBUS form.